# Does Rails 5.2 API mode swallow default security headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.2

If I output `config.action_dispatch.default_headers` in my `application.rb` I see all the [standard rails headers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#default-headers):

`{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "X-Download-Options"=>"noopen", "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies"=>"none", "Referrer-Policy"=>"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"}`

However if I then make a request to my app (with curl/browser/postman) I don't see any of the above. I only see the following:

```
$  curl -v -XGET 'localhost:4000/myresource/581'
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 4000 (#0)
> GET /myresource/581 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< ETag: W/"292a7d87b10e292374e765dd0b56fee7"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: 7ff75ff6-f598-4489-9439-a4c17c6a5480
< X-Runtime: 0.025049
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
```

This is all running locally with no web server/proxy. In production I am missing the same headers.

Is Rails API mode removing headers that it thinks are irrelevant for APIs? Or could it only be some other code in my app that is doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 5.x in API mode does not include the ActionDispatch default headers.

It is an issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34940.

But it is fixed now and will be available in version 6.0.0: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32484

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue a few months ago, as @Matheus mentioned they fixed that in `rails 6`, but in case you are stuck with `rails 5.2`, which was my case, here is how I fixed the issue, hope this helps! :

```rb
before_action :put_headers

  def put_headers
    response.set_header('Referrer-Policy', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin')
    response.set_header('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
    response.set_header('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN')
    response.set_header('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block')
    response.set_header('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self' https:; " \
        "img-src 'self' https:;" \
        "media-src 'none'; " \
        "object-src 'none'; " \
        "script-src 'self'; " \
        "style-src 'self' ")
  end
```

Be aware that the above is just an `example of configuration` means that you need to add your own logic to the configuration above for all the headers (e.g. content security policy), also be sure to set that code on the application controller ([this site may help with security configuration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/)).